Webapp with spring MVC with jsp as front end. Index.jsp as my landing page inside WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp.My Controller isn't being invoked
Okay,I am using spring MVC,jsp,Java Based Configuration. where index.jsp is my landing page which is inside WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp. I am aware that jsp files inside WEB-INF cannot be accessed directly through URL.So, i have set my Controller with @GetMapping("/") that return string "index" which is then handled by InternalResourceViewResolver, prefix as"/WEB-INF/jsp/" and suffix as".jsp".
When i run my app, "http://localhost:14639/project/" this is my URL and i get 404 not found,
"The requested resource [/project/] is not available". I have "Sysout" statement inside the controller with  @GetMapping("/") mapping, it isn't being invoked and also there is not any logs on console rather than tomcat starting.
and context path is "project".
package Configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="controller")
public class MainConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
    

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {javaBasedConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}

that is my DispatcherServlet
package Configurations;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controller.viewsController")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
     @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return resolver;
        }

     @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("/static/");
        }

}

that is my WebConfigurations
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello world..</h1>
</body>
</html>

That is my index.jsp
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class viewsController {
    
        @GetMapping("/")
         public String home() {
             System.out.println("i am working..");
                return "index"; // This maps to /WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
            }
       
    

    

}

That is my viewsController.
and,
this is my structure

Did you check a server log file to see your application isn't running.

Thank you for the response, i did check the log file inside tomcat installation directory and its empty. What does that mean and possible solution?

It might happens only if Tomcat wasn't started. In you case I would check the processes running to ensure the Tomcat instance is running. It is very complicated and doesn't fit SO topics. You should get support of sysadmin or ask your server topics on another site suitable for such questions. Here you can ask questions about programming not the software support.

That sound messed up, does deleting and reinstalling tomcat works?

Alright, solved.
I don't know how but there was new web module automatically creating in tomcat module, may be because i was using"/project/signin" as action.
I deleted tomcat from eclipse and readded it and solved
